# How to add a title to your Lightbox (v.2.5)

Tags: hyperlink, lightbox, addition, title

This is not a Question, just some advise I want to give to you.
After hours of googling and testing out, I didn't find a solution that worked on my lightbox. I don't know why, but I just couldn't apply a link into the title, not with `htmlentities()` etc.

So I came up with my own solution, which is just a workaround. 
I'm not really satisfied with myself but it's the only way it works for me.
So, if you're having the same troubles like me, just add this line of code:

Search for this line of Code in `lightbox.js` (In my file it was the line 277):

```
$lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast');
```

and replace it with this:

```
$lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html('<span onclick="window.location.href=\'http://yourdomain.com\'">'+this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title+"</span>").fadeIn('fast');
```

What did I do?

Since `.lb-caption` is added to display the title attribute, i just wrap the original output in an  element and bind a click event to a certain location.

Problem with it:
Since I wrapped around the whole title attribute, the whole title attribute becomes a link.

To get the cursor: pointer; effect in css and your standard link layout, just make the title a link. In this way it doesnt has to be `htmlentities()` decoded link.

**Example:**

```
<a href="img/image1.png" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" title="<a class"lightboxlink">This link opens a new page</a>
```

Another problem is: Now is the link static. (Since we're not using the href of our link).

**Solution:**

To add *One* `$_GET` Attribute to the link, we just need to fix a few lines.
What you do is, in your image call (the  part) you add the attribute "rev", means:

Instead of `<a href="img/image1.png" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" title="<a class"lightboxlink">This link opens a new page</a>`,

you now use (add the "rev" attribute"):

```
<a href="img/image1.png" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" rev="test" title="<a class"lightboxlink">This link opens a new page</a>
```

Now to the Javascript part...

Search for:

```
if ($link.attr('rel') === 'lightbox') {
    this.album.push({
```

this part, and replace:

```
link: $link.attr('href'),
      title: $link.attr('title'),
```

with

```
link: $link.attr('href'),
      title: $link.attr('title'),
      rev: $link.attr('rev')
```

If you go a few lines down you'll see the same part with link: $…., title: $…., replace that part with:

```
link: $(a).attr('href'),
      title: $(a).attr('title'),
      rev: $(a).attr('rev')
```

Now we just need to modify our  wrapper: (Go back to now line 279, before the $_GET part it was line 277)

```
    $lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html('<span onclick="window.location.href=\'http://yourdomain.comindex.php?page=contact&t='+this.album[this.currentImageIndex].rev+'\'">'+this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title+"</span>").fadeIn('fast');
```

We add now `'+this.album[this.currentImageIndex].rev+'` instead of the static part.

You can repeat this method to add infinite `$_GET` parameters, just add a new attribute to your image call, and change the javascript like we did in my explanation.

This is a really complicated and unusual way to solve the link in title problem, but its the only way how it will work in my script.

I hope that I helped someone! :)